How to modify hover color in lightning-datatable
I have a parent component which grabs data from an Apex class and feeds it to a child component, which is my datatable (this all works fine). I would like the hover row background and text color to be modifiable.
When my component loads, 'CSS loaded successfully' is logging properly in the console, but my CSS is not showing up. Any ideas where I could be going wrong?
Child Component HTML
<template>
    <lightning-datatable class="myTable"
        key-field="Id"
        data={inputData}
        columns={columns}
        hide-checkbox-column>
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>

Child Component JS
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import datatablecss from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/datatablecss';

export default class BasicDataTable extends LightningElement {
    @api inputData = [];
    @api columns = [];

    connectedCallback() {

        loadStyle(this, datatablecss).then(() => {
            console.log('CSS loaded successfully')
        })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error loading datatableStyles:', error);
      
          });
      
      }

}

CSS from Static Resource
.myTable tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: red !important;
}

